# appending header to file that does not exist then append after

Tags: c#, winforms

With some previous feedback from the community I have implemented a function which checks if  a file exists, if it doesn't then it writes the header and the data but if it does exist it only appends to it. Well that's what it's supposed to do but all it does is write the data without the headers. It's as if it jumps out of the first condition and just goes to the next one. Where am I going wrong?

```
private void button6_Click_2(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int count_row = dataGridView1.RowCount;
        int count_cell = dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells.Count;
        string path = "C:\\Users\\jdavis\\Desktop\\" + comboBox5.Text + ".csv";
        string rxHeader = "Code" + "," + "Description" + "," + "NDC" + "," + "Supplier Code"
        + "," + "Supplier Description" + "," + "Pack Size" + "," + "UOM";


        MessageBox.Show("Please wait while " + comboBox5.Text + " table is being exported..");

        for (int row_index = 0; row_index <= count_row - 2; row_index++)
        {

            for (int cell_index = 1; cell_index <= count_cell - 1; cell_index++)
            {
                textBox8.Text = textBox8.Text + dataGridView1.Rows[row_index].Cells[cell_index].Value.ToString() + ",";

            }
            textBox8.Text = textBox8.Text + "\r\n";

            if (!File.Exists(path))
            {
                System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path, rxHeader);
                System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path, textBox8.Text);
            }
            else
            {    
                System.IO.File.AppendAllText(path, textBox8.Text);
                MessageBox.Show("Export  of " + comboBox5.Text + " table is complete!");
                textBox8.Clear();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Pretty sure you want the 2nd call to be `Append`, not `Write`. Change to this: `System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path, rxHeader);` `System.IO.File.AppendAllText(path, textBox8.Text);`. Without this change the second call basically deletes the file, then writes only `textBox8.Text` to it.

Comment: @Quantic This works to an extent but the issue am having is that the header and the first record adds ok but when I close the program and append a new record. It duplicates the existing record and then adds the new record I added. (my data is stored in my database in which I save to it and expot to the CSV file through my c# application) Am not sure if that matters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `File.WriteAllText` overrides the content of the file, so your 2nd `File.WriteAllText` overrides the headers.  You can change your code as follows:

```
        if (!File.Exists(path))
        {
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path, rxHeader + textBox8.Text);
        }
        else
        {    
            System.IO.File.AppendAllText(path, textBox8.Text);
            MessageBox.Show("Export  of " + comboBox5.Text + " table is complete!");
            textBox8.Clear();
        }
```

Comment: ok this works to an extent. First the program writes the header alone to the file. I have to write to the file a second time for the data to be added. But here is the weird part, the data first writes to file as a duplicate then adds the third data. So basically two same entries and then one entry

Comment: Figured out the problem. Thank you.